# ArgoCD : error creating SSH agent: "SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified"

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, yaml, argocd, argo-workflows

**rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error creating SSH agent: "SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified"**

```bash
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: argo-application
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default

  source:
    repoURL: git@github.com:rwiteshbera/argo-cd-app-config.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: src
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: myapp # if it doesn't exist, argocd will create

  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true

    automated:
      selfHeal: true # If we manually run kubectl apply, it will sync the git repository
      prune: true
```

Getting such error while using SSH in repoURL. But it is working properly for my GitLab web URL (https). Can anyone please explain why it is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SSH` key template to connect the repository using `SSH`.

Because `SSH` use key for authentication while `HTTPS` does not required authentication for public repository.

> SSH, aka git@github.com: or ssh://git@github.com/
> Uses public-key authentication. You have to generate a keypair (or "public key"), then add it to your GitHub account.
> A minor **downside is that authentication is needed for all connections, so you always need a GitHub account** – even to pull or clone.

[GitHub protocol comparison](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747)

argocd-domain.com -> setting -> repository -> connect as ssh
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if you can use read-only Tokens for Git-Access. I could get rid of the SSH-Agent error in prefering HTTPS over SSH. Several solutions to mitigate the SSH-Agent haven't worked for me. I also couldn't access the Git-Server logs... It might be due to that server where Git runs despite the ArgoCD server error. The error actually clearly states and would let me infer it is an issue on ArgoCD Server.